# assigning derived class pointer to base class pointer in C++

Tags: c++

I have following

```
class base
{
};

class derived : public base
{
  public:
   derived() {}
   void myFunc() { cout << "My derived function" << std::endl; }

};
```

now I have

```
base* pbase = new derived();
  pbase->myFunc();
```

I am getting error myFunc is not a member function of base.

How to avoid this? and how to make myFunc get called?

Note I should have base class contain no function as it is part of design and above code is part of big function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are adamant that this function should NOT be a part of base, you have but 2 options to do it.

Either use a pointer to derived class

```
derived* pDerived = new derived();
pDerived->myFunc();
```

Or (**uglier** & ***vehemently* discouraged**) static_cast the pointer up to derived class type and then call the function
**NOTE**: To be used **with caution**. Only use when you are SURE of the type of the pointer you are casting, i.e. you are sure that `pbase` is a `derived` or a type derived from `derived`. In this particular case its ok, but im guessing this is only an example of the actual code.

```
base* pbase = new derived();
static_cast<derived*>(pbase)->myFunc();
```

Comment: The `static_cast` is pretty unsafe here. It could easily lead to all kinds of trouble.

Comment: The `static_cast` would not return a null pointer in some cases where the `dynamic_cast` would. For example, it would allow to cast from a `derived2` object to a `derived` one, even of they are not in the same inheritance branch.

Comment: Any benefit of assigning derived class pointer to base class? I guess virtual is different case and in case function is not virtual, is there any usage of this? In case there is a override, accessing function using base class pointer will access base class function only. So I am not sure of the usage.

Answer (score 6):

`myfunc` needs to be accessible from the base class, so you would have to declare a public virtual `myfunc` in `base`. You could make it pure virtual if you intend for `base` to be an abstract base class, i.e one that cannot be instantiated and acts as an interface:

```
class base
{
 public:
  virtual void myfunc() = 0; // pure virtual method
};
```

If you ant to be able to instantiate `base` objects then you would have to provide an implementation for `myfunc`:

```
class base
{
 public:
  virtual void myfunc() {}; // virtual method with empty implementation 
};
```

There is **no other clean way to do this** if you want to access the function from a pointer to a base class. The safetest option is to use a `dynamic_cast`

```
base* pbase = new derived;

....
derived* pderived = dynamic_cast<derived*>(pbase);
if (derived) {
  // do something
} else {
  // error
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `myfunc()` be a public member?

Answer (score 3):

To use the base class pointer, you *must* change the base class definition to be:

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual void myFunc() { }
};
```

I see no other way around it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You could add it as a member of base and make it a virtual or pure virtual function. If using this route however, you should also add a virtual destructor in the base class to allow successful destruction of inherited objects.

```
class base
{
public:
   virtual ~base(){};
   virtual void myFunc() = 0;
};

class derived : public base
{
  public:
   derived() {}
   void myFunc() { cout << "My derived function" << std::endl; }

};
```

Comment: Making it protected would make it impossible to call the method from a `base*`.